# How to change the colour of a key text in a custom keyboard?

Tags: android, mobile, custom-keyboard, ime

I've writing a simple input method editor and I'm a bit stuck on changing the colour of the actual Key. 
Here is my keyboardView which is located in `res/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview">

</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```

my key_background:

```
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal"
    />

<item

    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
    />
```

, the normal state

```
<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and the pressed state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/keyboard_pressed"/>

</shape>
```

So I am stuck changing the colour of the actual symbols (ie a, b, c etc) to black. Please see attached screen shot with what I got so far. 
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To change the text color programatically at run time:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/75629152/17002571](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75629152/17002571)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [KeyboardView Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView#attr_android:keyTextColor) :

```
android:keyTextColor
```

You can add this attribute to your KeyboardView

*Color to use for the label in a key.*

*May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".*